# Connect and log in to a different database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to connect to a different database. I have a script for creating a new instance from an SQL file. I am creating users by inserting into the main database table and then using the same database as the master login table with all the users. I am trying to login to another database and use that database. I am getting a blank home page on trying to login to another database and also in some cases I am not able to connect to another database at all and end up using the same master db. I am storing the company name in a session and using it in all model files and connecting to the db. I tried everything but nothing seems to work. My controller model and view files are as follows:

model: mod_login.php

```
<?php 
    class mod_login extends CI_Model{
        var $myTables;
        #print_r($this->db->last_query());

        function  __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $companyName = $companyName = $this->session->userdata('company');
            $otherdb = $this->load->database("$companyName", TRUE);
            $this->myTables=$this->config->item('myTables');
            $this->load->helper('cookie');   
        }

        function validate_admin_login(){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('userpass', 'Password', 'trim|required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
                return $this->check_admin_login();
            }else{
                return validation_errors();
            }

        }
        function check_cookie_login(){

            $this->db->where('username', trim($this->input->cookie('uusername')));
            $this->db->where('userpass ', sha1(trim($this->input->cookie('userpass'))));
            $this->db->where('status', '1');
            $this->db->where('deleted', '0');
            $this->db->select('*');
            $query = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users']);

            if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                $row = $query->row();
                $this->db->where('userid', $row->id);
                $this->db->select('firstname,lastname,profileimage');
                $query1 = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users_details']);
                $row1 = $query1->row();
                $newdata = array(
                                    'is_admin_logged_in' => true,
                                    'admin_user_name' => $row->username,
                                    'admin_userpass' => $row->userpass,
                                    'admin_id'=>$row->id,
                                    'admin_lastlogin'=>date("d-m-Y H:i:s",$row->lastlogin),
                                    'admin_lastloginip'=>$row->lastloginip,
                                    'lastrefresh'=>time() 
                            );

                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata); 
                $this->update_admin_login_time($this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
                $this->admin_init_elements->set_global_user($row->username,$row->userpass);
                if($this->input->post('remember'))
                {
                    $cookie = array('name'   => 'username','value'  => $row->username,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
                    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
                }
                $name = $row1->firstname.' '.$row1->lastname;
                $cookie1 = array('name'   => 'name','value'  => $name,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
                $this->input->set_cookie($cookie1); 
                $cookie2 = array('name'   => 'image','value'  => $row1->profileimage,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
                $this->input->set_cookie($cookie2); 


                return 'Login Successful';
            }else{

            }

        }
function check_admin_login(){

            $this->db->where('username', trim($this->input->post('username')));
            $this->db->where('userpass ', sha1(trim($this->input->post('userpass'))));
            $this->db->where('status', '1');
            $this->db->where('deleted', '0');
            $this->db->select('*');
            $query = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users']);
            if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                $row = $query->row();
                $this->db->where('userid', $row->id);
                $this->db->select('firstname,lastname,profileimage,company');
                    //$query1 = $this->db->query("Select * from pr_users_details where userid = '".$row->id."'");
                $query1 = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users_details']);
                $row1 = $query1->row();
                $newdata = array(
                                    'is_admin_logged_in' => true,
                                    'admin_user_name' => $row->username,
                                    'admin_userpass' => $row->userpass,
                                    'admin_id'=>$row->id,
                                    'admin_lastlogin'=>date("d-m-Y H:i:s",$row->lastlogin),
                                    'admin_lastloginip'=>$row->lastloginip,
                                    'lastrefresh'=>time(),
                                    'company'=>$row1->company
                            );
                            $company = $row1->company;
                    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata); 
            $companyName = $this->session->userdata('company');
            $otherdb = $this->load->database("$companyName", TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
echo "</pre>";



                $this->update_admin_login_time($this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
                $this->admin_init_elements->set_global_user($row->username,$row->userpass);
                if($this->input->post('remember'))
                {
                    $cookie = array('name'   => 'username','value'  => $row->username,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
                    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
                }
                $name = $row1->firstname.' '.$row1->lastname;
                $cookie1 = array('name'   => 'name','value'  => $name,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
                $this->input->set_cookie($cookie1); 
                $cookie2 = array('name'   => 'image','value'  => $row1->profileimage,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
                $this->input->set_cookie($cookie2); 


                return 'Login Successful';
            }else{
                return 'Incorrect Username or Password.';
            }

        }
```

Controller: login.php

```
<?php
class login extends CI_Controller
{
    var $data;

    function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('cookie');  

        $is_admin_logged_in = $this->admin_init_elements->admin_logged_in_status();  
        global $USER;
        if($is_admin_logged_in == TRUE){
            redirect('home');
            //;
        }

        //populate viewfor header / footer elements

        $this->admin_init_elements->init_elements('N');
        $this->load->model('mod_login');

    }

    function index(){
        //if Admin already logged in, send to Admin home

        $this->data['message']='';
        $this->data['msg_class'] = '';
        $post_array=$this->input->post();

        $data['old_images']=$this->mod_common->getBgImages();

        if($this->input->cookie('remember') == 'on')
        {
            //echo $this->input->cookie('username');
            $this->data['message']=strip_tags($this->mod_login->check_cookie_login());
            if($this->data['message']=='Login Successful'){
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
                 redirect('home');              
            }else{
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'gagal';
            }
        } 
        if($this->input->post('action')=='adminLogin'){

        //print_r($this->input->post()); die;

            if(isset($post_array['remember'])){
                $username_cookie= array(
                    'name'   => 'uusername',
                    'value'  => $post_array['username'],
                    'expire' => '865000',
                    'secure' => FALSE
                );

                $password_cookie= array(
                    'name'   => 'userpass',
                    'value'  => $post_array['userpass'],
                    'expire' => '865000',
                    'secure' => FALSE
                );

                $remember_cookie= array(
                    'name'   => 'remember',
                    'value'  => 'on',
                    'expire' => '865000',
                    'secure' => FALSE
                );

                $this->input->set_cookie($username_cookie); 
                $this->input->set_cookie($password_cookie); 
                $this->input->set_cookie($remember_cookie); 
                //die;

            }
            else
            {
                if($this->input->cookie('remember') == 'on')
                {
                    if($this->input->cookie('uusername') != $post_array['username'])
                    {
                        delete_cookie("remember");
                        delete_cookie("uusername");
                        delete_cookie("userpass");
                    }
                } 
            }

            $this->data['message']=strip_tags($this->mod_login->validate_admin_login());
            if($this->data['message']=='Login Successful'){
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
                 redirect('home');              
            }else{
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'gagal';
            }
        } /*else if(isset()){

        }*/


    ///////////////////////
        $this->data['cookieRemember'] = $this->input->cookie('remember');
        $this->data['cookieUsername'] = $this->input->cookie('username');
        $this->data['cookiePassword'] = $this->input->cookie('userpass');
        //echo $this->data['cookieRemember'];echo $this->data['cookieUsername']; echo $this->data['cookiePassword'];
    //////////////////////

        $this->data['cookiename']  = $this->input->cookie('name', false);
        $this->data['cookieimage'] = $this->input->cookie('image', false);

        $sess_msg = $this->session->userdata('session_msg');
        $session_msg_class = $this->session->userdata('session_msg_class');
        if(isset($sess_msg) && $sess_msg!= ''){
            $this->data['message']=$sess_msg;
            $this->data['msg_class'] = $session_msg_class!=''?$session_msg_class:'gagal';
        }
        //render full layout, specific to this function
        $this->load->view('login', $this->data);
    }
```

View: home.php

```
<?php
class home extends CI_Controller
{
    var $data;

    function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        //populate viewfor header / footer elements

        $this->admin_init_elements->init_elements();
        #$this->load->model('admin_m');

    }

    function index(){

        $data = array();
        //if Admin already logged in, send to Admin home
        #$this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/gridview',$data,TRUE);
        $data['lastlogin_details'] = $this->admin_lastlogin_details();
        $this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/dashboard',$data,true);
        //render full layout, specific to this function
        $this->load->view('layout', $this->data);

    }

    function admin_lastlogin_details(){
        $lastlogin_det['lastlogin'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_lastlogin');
        $lastlogin_det['lastloginip'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_lastloginip');
        return $lastlogin_det;
    }
```

It displays the home.php but it displays a blank page without errors

Comment: You should make sure that each class and file name only has the first letter upper case. explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: i had an issue on AWS and made it small